# Changing PuTTy font appearance to match cmd

Tags: cmd.exe, putty

As the title says, I'd like to change the font appearance of PuTTy to match that of CMD's. Both are set to use the Consolas font. CMD uses a size of 14 and PuTTy 10 since 14 was too big.

My problem is that PuTTy's font is much thicker.

CMD:
[image]

PuTTy:
[image]

I use a Windows 10 Pro system with a 4K screen.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly - you did not find that when open a putty there is a section Window -> Appearance where you can change look and feel, not only fonts, of putty.

Comment: I have tried just about every combination of those. They don't fix this issue.